# ImageView usando kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hola tengo dudas en cómo crear un evento que al dar click sobre un imgeView me muestre la imagen en pantalla completa usando kotlin

Answer (score 0):

espero que te sirva mi código y sino te ayudo con gusto.

```
        imagenView.setOnClickListener {
     
        val dialog = Dialog(context) // pasar el contexto donde ocurre está acción
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) // para que remueva el título de la barra superior "actionBar"
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_imagen) //un layout con un imageView 
        // ocupando todo el espacio ancho y alto match_parent
        val popup = dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupImagen) as ImageView
        //  el ID del imageView del layout a mostrar en pantalla completa
        popup.setImageBitmap(BitmapMostrar) //pasar la imagen a mostrar
        dialog.show() // muestra el popup
    }
```

Este código crea un dialog para que sea como un popup de la imagen seleccionada, si está en un recycler view podes pasarle la misma imagen que está en el ítem, ejemplo holder.imagen como bitmap al popup.

Comment: Ampliale un poco mas la respuesta, explicando como funciona el codigo.